# javascript how to convert array into object

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, object

good morning everyone, I know this question was asked several times, but I tried to take a look and I could not solve the problem.
I'm using an owlCarousel library to iterate through a dynamic wordpress gallery. 
this is the standard code at the moment:

```
var owl = jQuery('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
  margin: 10,
  loop: true,
  responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      600: {
        items: 2
      },
      1000: {
        items: 3
      },
      1000: {
        items: 4
      }
  }
  })
```

everything works normally making me view 4 images in the gallery.
I would like to create as many items as the number of posts of my custom post type in wordpress, so I created a variable called **baratto_obj.n_activity** where an array of requested objects arrives with a custom loop.
so I tested this code:

```
jsonObj = [];
    jQuery(baratto_obj.n_attivita).each(function(index) {

        item = {
          items: index +1
        }
        jsonObj.push(item);
    });
    console.log(jsonObj)
```

what arrives is an array of objects:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {items: 1}
1: {items: 2}
2: {items: 3}
```

but I can't transform it this way:

```
{
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      600: {
        items: 2
      },
      1000: {
        items: 3
      },
      1000: {
        items: 4
      }
```

so as to give it as a parameter to the owlCarousel function.
the end result would be something like this

```
owl.owlCarousel({
  margin: 10,
  loop: true,
  responsive: myobject
  })
```

Someone would have the patience to give me a tip. Thanks in advance

Comment: use object instead of array, `jsonObj = {}` and then use `index` as key

Comment: i tried but probabily .. 
I probably had something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the array to an object. This preserves the indices as properties.

```js
var array = [{ items: 1 }, { items: 2 }, { items: 3 }],
    object = Object.assign({}, array);

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something in your question and examples you should be creating your empty JSON object like one of these ways:

```
var objectA = {}
var objectB = new Object()
```

Your example is creating an empty array but it looks like you need all JSON, not any array of JSON objects.